# null pointer in postDataTimestamp - CameraSource.cpp (Stagefright)

Tags: shared-memory, android-camera, stagefright

Currently, I m trying to access the camera data and send it to default encoder from my application.

I need to access the data returned by camera in postDataTimestamp() in camerasource.cpp. On checking the data pointer I found it was null. But in postData() it is a valid pointer.

I get "cannot map bpMemoryHeap error" when i try to print the data pointer in postdatatimestamp().. I m not sure why I get this prob.

On discussing, heard since the camera and my application are running in two different process and so I get this error and I cannot access the cameraData in postDataTimestamp().

Can someone shed some light on this issue..?

Thanks.